# Constraints using categorical/ordinal variables in SEM (EQS)

Tags: ordinal-data, structural-equation-modeling, constraint

First of all, thank you for helping me out.

At the moment, I am doing a term paper for my structural equation modeling class. My university teaches with EQS, but maybe this is not important at all.
For one factor I use 4-point Likert scales. To be correct, I defined them as ordinal variables. When I do so, polychoric correlation instead of covariances are used to calculate independencies. But when I specify a multi-group model and equalize the error variances of group 1 and 2 to save degrees of freedom, an error  occurs, e.g.:

> Parameter E4, E4 in Group 1 is functionally dependent on other
>    parameters, and must be removed from all equality and inequality constraints.

When I do not define them as categorial, no problems occur.
This happened already with two different models to me.
I use a ML robust estimator; residuals and multivariate kurtosis seem to be ok!

Any suggestions?

Thank you again.

Comment: I don't use EQS so I don't know about this error specifically, but I think this is occurring because of the dependency between the mean and the variance in a dichotomous (or ordinal) variable. If you have a dichotomous variable, and you know the mean (or the threshold), then you know the variance. You cannot treat them as separate parameters . When you equalize the variances, EQS is saying "Right, you want variances, you can't have means then".  (Is it multiple groups?)